# FFmpeg/FFplay sometimes goes to sleep waiting on IO when webcam is unplugged

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, webcam, v4l2

I made a webcam viewer out of a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, FFmpeg/FFplay, and v4l2. I have a udev rule that automatically starts an FFmpeg stream and brings up FFplay to view it when my webcam is plugged in and I have another udev rule to close FFplay when the webcam is unplugged.

This works for the most part but the only problem is that sometimes instead of closing, FFplay will go into an interruptible sleep state for a couple minutes before closing. I need it to close immediately. I ran `strace` while this was happening and it seems to be waiting on IO operations. Even when sending a `kill` signal it still won't close for a few minutes.

Here's a snippet of how the `strace` output looks:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=7465, tv_nsec=164876860}) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=10000000}, 0xbeb96948) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=7465, tv_nsec=179573716}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=7465, tv_nsec=180091711}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=7465, tv_nsec=180544707}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=7465, tv_nsec=182013692}) = 0
write(2, "7465.10 M-V:  0.024 fd=   3 aq= "..., 69) = 69
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=10000000}, 0xbeb96948) = 0
```

Any ideas how I can get FFplay to close immediately every time the webcam is unplugged?

Comment: I was recording an audio stream by ffmpeg (3.4.8) and there was a temporary problem with internet connection and maybe with router. Anyway ffmpeg got in interruptible sleep state and did not continue even after internet connection started to work. I had to interrupt the process. Unfortunately I did not inspect using `strace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly which part fixed it but I removed FFmpeg and just played the webcam back with FFplay instead. I also run the following script when the webcam is unplugged:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pkill -15 ffplay
sudo pkill -9 ffplay
```

It doesn't appear to freeze for as long when unplugging the webcam now.

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept our own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the tick icon.